# Monitoring SOlution for Arduino

Tags: arduino, protocols, suggestbox

I have an Arduino project for solar tracker running. Initially I used the serial monitor to view data with my laptop. Now I'm moving my project about 1000 meters from my home. I want to remotely monitor the data from solar tracker parameter like date, time, track angle, coordinates, etc. updated every 15 minutes.

What would the best best protocol used for long distance transmission? Should I do zigbee, wireless, ethernet, modbus? If particular protocol suggested let me know why it being suggested. I also want to use the least number of pins to do this.

I Googled it and I found an ethernet shield with SD card. I never wanted it to get recorded on a SD card. The data should go directly to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use a cable connection, as they are the most reitable.
RS485 is the best for bucket (100 kbit/s at 1200 m), optical fiber is very expansive but optimal.
classic ethernet has range of 100meter, wifi without special equipment about 50/100m, some zibee has a maximal range of 1Km, so MAY be the solution, but are at their limit.

Modbus is a "high level" protocol that can be used over RS485 (or other connection)